# How to generally refer to the last generated (<-) object (in my case a data.frame) in R?

Tags: r

I like to write a loop or function that evaluates the name (!) of the last generated data.frame. Depending on the name of the last used data frame, I would like to do certain operations.

```
   df_head <- data.frame("age" = c(19, 21), 
               sex = c("m", "f"))


    ifelse(  str_detect(deparse(substitute(df_head)), "head", negate = FALSE),
         head(df_head), tail(df_head)
         ) 

    df_tail <- data.frame("age" = c(17, 04), 
                          sex = c("m", "f"))


    ifelse(  str_detect(deparse(substitute(df_tail)), "head", negate = FALSE),
             head(df_tail), tail(df_tail)
    )
```

I create multiple data frames, such as df_head and df_tail in my example.
Dependent on their name, I will perform plenty of data transformations. I do not always want to copy the contingent data transformations, paste the names in the respective place and so on...

Instead I want something shorter such as:

```
 df_head <- data.frame("age" = c(19, 21), 
                   sex = c("m", "f"))


       x <- last generated Dataset 

ifelse(str_detect(deparse(substitute(x)), "head", negate = FALSE),
                 head(x), tail(x)
        )


    df_tail <- data.frame("age" = c(17, 04), 
                              sex = c("m", "f"))

   x <- last generated dataset 

ifelse(str_detect(deparse(substitute(x)), "head", negate = FALSE),
                 head(x), tail(x)
        )
```

However I do not know, how to refer to/ grab the last generated dataset.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to read about [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question is fairly abstract right now. We could help you better if you showed us what you've tried, what your data looks like, and what the output should look like. You obviously need some kind of looping structure. Have you tried for-loops or *apply functions?

Comment: Dear gersht, thank you. My problem is not the loop, but I made it more concrete.

Comment: You could use `ls()` but not sure how you can sort that by creation time. Or just use `get/mget` assuming you know what the last generated data_set is named. Your next line seems to suggest that.

Comment: Dear NelsonGon ls() seems promising but does not work. I tried it like: `df_head <- data.frame("age" = c(19, 21), 
           sex = c("m", "f"))


ifelse(  str_detect(deparse(substitute(get())), "head", negate = FALSE),
     head(get()), tail(get())
     )`

Comment: When you create a dataframe just store its name in a variable `last_name`. You can then use that in `ifelse`, e.g. `ifelse(grepl("head", last_name), …)`.

Comment: Have you tried system variable `.Last.value`?

Answer (score 1):

R doesn't keep a record of previous commands that is detailed enough to do what you want.  Some front ends to R do, but not all.

If you're using one of those front ends, this code might work:

```
lastAssigned <- function(match = "<- *data.frame",
                         remove = " *<-.*") {
  f <- tempfile()
  savehistory(f)
  history <- readLines(f)
  unlink(f)
  match <- grep(match, history, value = TRUE)
  sub(remove, "", match[length(match)])
}
```

After your first statement, I see

```
> lastAssigned()
[1] "df_head"
```

However, it depends on you always doing assignments using a particular pattern of code, so it's not very general.

Comment: I tried your code as follows: `lastAssigned() #works

#using 
ifelse(  str_detect(deparse(substitute(lastAssigned())), "head", negate = FALSE),
     head(lastAssigned()), tail(lastAssigned())
     ) `
This does not give the head of df_head, but it gives the letters df_head. Which front end did you use it on?

Comment: I used RStudio.  It doesn't give the contents of the variable:  the function just gives its name.  You could use `get()` to retrieve the variable using its name.

Comment: Short Follow Up Question, is the lastAssigned function able to override itsself? 

Because for a funny reason I do not get "df_head" out of it, even if I last assigned new functions in R with RStudio.  Thanks for help!

Comment: If you have a different question, you should post it as a different question.  You're welcome to include my function as part of your question, and should also describe what you did, what you got, and what you expected to get.