# LastAssigned (In R what was last right of an arrow (<-) and returning that)

Tags: r, rstudio

I try to create an R function that returns the data frame I last created. I use R studio. The idea and current solution from this question stems from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57132909/how-to-generally-refer-to-the-last-generated-object-in-my-case-a-data-fram/57136834?noredirect=1#comment100815520_57136834)

```
lastAssigned <- function(match = "<- *data.frame",
                         remove = " *<-.*") {
  f <- tempfile()
  savehistory(f)
  history <- readLines(f)
  unlink(f)
  match <- grep(match, history, value = TRUE)
  sub(remove, "", match[length(match)])
}
```

However the current function returns the name. I now would need a function returning the data.frame.

I would be very happy if someone could please point me in the right direction.

Intended usage:

```
df_head <- data.frame("age" = c(19, 21), 
                      sex = c("m", "f"))
lastAssigned() 
library(data.table)
setDT(lastAssigned())
#gives error (obviously)

alittlefunction <-function(x){
  sexy <- rev(c('m', 'f'))
  x <- within(x, sex <- factor(sex, levels=sexy))
}

alittlefunction(lastAssigned())
#gives error (obviously)
```

How could I rebuild lastAssigned in a way it will work for this usage?

Answer (score 1):

You can use '**get**' over here, :). Like below,

```
lastAssigned <- function(match = "<- *data.frame",
                         remove = " *<-.*") {
    f <- tempfile()
    savehistory(f)
    history <- readLines(f)
    unlink(f)
    match <- grep(match, history, value = TRUE)
    return(get(sub(remove, "", match[length(match)]), envir = .GlobalEnv))
}


alittlefunction <-function(x){
    sexy <- rev(c('m', 'f'))
    x <- within(x, sex <- factor(sex, levels=sexy))
    return(x)
}
```

It should generate correct output as you expect, I believe unless I misunderstood something here.

**Edit**: Just a note, As mentioned in comments, you also need to provide environment name to avoid conflicts, also you can use `pos` instead of `envir`.

From the documentation:

> The pos argument can specify the environment in which to look for the
>   object in any of several ways: as a positive integer (the position in
>   the search list); as the character string name of an element in the
>   search list

Running the function: `lastAssigned()` gives a dataframe `df_head`

A simple example can help you to understand:

```
x <- 2
get('x') will return 2.
```

I hope this is what you were expecting. Thanks

You can also use **parse** function over here, like you can replace the entire return with below line:

```
return(eval(parse(text =sub(remove, "", match[length(match)])), envir = .GlobalEnv ))
```

Comment: As with the other answer, you need to specify the `envir` or `pos` argument to `get()`.

Comment: @user2554330 , Thanks very much for the added Info

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking for. Something like this:

```
getLastAssigned <- function(match = "<- *data.frame",
                         remove = " *<-.*") {
  f <- tempfile()
  savehistory(f)
  history <- readLines(f)
  unlink(f)
  match <- grep(match, history, value = TRUE)
  get(sub(remove, "", match[length(match)]), envir = .GlobalEnv)


}


df_head <- data.frame("age" = c(19, 21), 
                      sex = c("m", "f"))

> getLastAssigned()
  age sex
1  19   m
2  21   f
```

Comment: You need to specify the `envir` or `pos` arguments to `get`, or it could look in the wrong place.  For example, if the dataframe was named `f`, you'd get the local variable, not the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the advise! I updated my answer accordingly. Since it works without specifying the envir argument, I tend to forget it, but your right, it might lead to errors.

Comment: I am always getting an error if I put that , Environ = .GlobalEnv "Error in sub(remove, "", match[length(match)], envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
  unused argument (envir = .GlobalEnv)"

Comment: Strange. I just reproduced the example on a different machine. Are you sure that all brackets and commas are correct? Have you placed the get() function around the sub()-call?